# How to delete elements from arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, element

```
private static void printInvoice() {

    for (int i = customerList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int n = taskChecker.size() -1; n >=0 ; i--){
        System.out.println(customerList.get(i).getName());
        customerList.get(i).invoiceForCustomer();
        taskChecker.remove(n);    

    }
}
```

This is whats get printed out:

```
Sven 9900 Task: Rosta knäck Date: 2014-02-11 Numbers of hours: 1
Tor 4950 Task: Rosta bröd Date: 2013-12-12 Numbers of hours: 1
Oden 4950 Task: Rosta bröd  Date: 2013-12-12  Numbers of hours: 1
```

Now I want to delete the tasks (Oden 4950 Task: Rosta bröd  Date: 2013-12-12 Numbers of hours: 1) after I've printed them out. I'm really confused over how I should do this...

Comment: Use `Iterator` from the `List` and call `Iterator#remove` rather than `List#remove`.

Comment: for(int i = taskChecker.size() -1; i >=0 ; i--) is probably wrong. You meant for(int n = taskChecker.size() -1; n >=0 ; n--), I bet. You need to decrease n here.

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. I bet you need to rethink it. At least it does not print what you written.

Comment: Didn't you [Just ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989101/how-to-delete-elements-from-arraylist) and got answers a few hours ago?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove items from a list you a currently looping through without using an `Iterator`. It constitutes a `ConcurrentModificationException`. As the comment to your issue states, use an `Iterator` object in order to allow deletion from the list you are operating on.

Just as a simple example of `Iterator` usage:

```
Iterator<Object> it = listOfObjects.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Object o = it.next();
    it.remove(); <--- removes the last object returned from Iterator.next() from the underlying collection
}
```